# Subsetting Sentinel 2 image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: sentinel-2, google-earth-engine

I am new to Google Earth Engine and I am working with Sentinel-2 imagery for landcover classification.

I need to limit the Sentinel 2 images to a specific study area i.e. Area of Interest. What specific commands do I need to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for taking the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 5):

What you do in EarthEngine is create a collection of Sentinel-2 images that you *filter* according to your criteria.

For instance if you want to limit your AOI to the map area in the code editor:

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
 .filterBounds(Map.getBounds(true))
```

You could also draw a polygon, name it AOI and filter to it. It might also be a good idea to filter by time:

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
 .filterBounds(AOI)
 .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')
```

Comment: Many thanks Kersten. This has worked well! I discovered another method that works:                                                                                                   var clippedImage = image.clip(feature)   whereby I created a rectangle with the area bounds and then clipped the median sentinel image with that rectangle.